# "Curses in this item are reflected back to you": What does it mean?

Tags: path-of-exile

[image: Image on item]

The glove shows an additional stat stated

> Curses in this item are reflected back to you.

What exactly does it mean by that statement? (An example would be nice too)

Comment: Note that it is "in" and not "on" (which you wrote in the title). And note that skill gems are put *in* an item.

Comment: I never really get why there are 'On Death' effects, isn't one of the main aim of games to not die(considering the penalty of death)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means, casting a curse , which is socketed in those gloves, will be cast on the Caster too (but only works with self-casted curses, [see](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Shackles_of_the_Wretched).)

An example of its usage: You could use this mechanic to cast Temporal Chains on yourself, increasing the duration of buffs like Immortal Call.